# Как получить ключ для Google Speech Api

Tags: google-speech-recognition

Хочу распознавать аудиофайлы. Раньше я уже использовал его. Генерировал ключ.
Если использовать запросы как [тут](https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2) с ключом [отсюда](http://tuarisa.ru/2014/08/google-speech-api-v2-dlya-chajnikov/), то все распознается.
А как свой ключ сгенерировать?

Comment: По вашей второй ссылке описано как его получить.

Comment: @Isaev создаю ключь на странице (учетные данные, меню слева). Затем создать учетные данные - > ключь API. И он не работает, в ответ приходит, что ключь не верен.

Comment: Внимательнее читаем: Получить API ключ довольно просто (хотя и не тривиально). Необходимо залогиниться под своей учетной записью, зайти на консоль разработчиков, создать новый проект. Перейти слева в раздел APIs и попытаться найти там Speech API. Когда вы его там в списке не нашли, заходим в группу Chromium Dev, вступаем в нее. Снова обновляем страничку APIs, видимо, что Speech API там появился. (у меня сразу был в списке)
API-key создается в Creditionals -> Create new Key -> Server key -> Create. Все. Ключ готов.

Comment: Спасибо! Надо было зайти в группу Chromium Dev.

Answer (score 1):

На [данной странице](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started) указанной платформы, есть блок "Set up your project" по быстрому получению ключа с кнопками. Для работы требуется минимальное знание английского языка.

Далее, формат который использовался на  API v2 поменялся, и теперь используется новая версия запросов, которая отправляется на https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize, а сам файл посылается в теле запроса в кодировке base64 через JSON.

```
{
  'config': {
    'encoding':'FLAC',
    'sampleRate':16000,
    'languageCode':'en-US'
  },
  'audio': {
    'content': 'ZkxhQwAAACIQABAAAAUJABtAA+gA8AB+W8FZndQvQAyjv...'
  }
}
```

Подробнее об этом формате запроса на [официальной странице проекта](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/base64-encoding)

Comment: Какой-то сложный способ....А есть более простой?
https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2 здесь я использовал простой запрос с ключом. Как этот ключь мне сгененрировать?